# List files in a folder, in the parent directory

Tags: python-3.x, file, filesystems

I know you can list the files of a directory with:

```
os.listdir('FOLDER_DIR')
```

But how do i list the files in a folder that exists in a directory above where i am right now?

For example, consider the following folder structure:

----PARENT

-------sub_dir1

-------sub_dir2

If my python program is in `sub_dir2`, how can i list the contents of folder `sub_dir1`, without changing directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `os.listdir('../sub_dir1')`